# How to generate permanent React keys for same string value in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a textbox where a user enters text. A search for specific keywords is then performed and the string is split at these keywords.

A first input may look like E.g.

```
[
    0: "this is "
    1: "word"
    2: " a form field value with another "
    3: "word"
]
```

A change then might be made to remove the first repeated word:

```
[
    0: "this is "
    1: " a form field value with another "
    2: "word"
]
```

How can I create a persistent key for each array item? I need the second `word` value to have the same React key as when it is first generated regardless of array position. It is a separate component instance regardless of the same value. I have an issue right now where deleting one of the split words will delete both due to the keys changing after the first word is deleted.

Best practices say not to use the array index, but I'm unsure in this situation how else to generate a unique key.

Comment: In your case it seems like you can probably use Index only or combine index with word content like `${index}${value}`

Comment: Use value as key.

Comment: Thanks @xdeepakv, but keys need to be unique. Same words would have same key.

Comment: Please check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough solution, but you can think of as a dictionary program.

```js
class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      words: ["this is ", "word", " a form field value with another ", "word"]
    };
    this.wordMap = this.state.words.reduce((m, x, index) => {
      m[index] = x;
      return m;
    }, {});
  }
  cleanWord() {
    let unique = new Set();
    for (let key in this.wordMap) {
      if (unique.has(this.wordMap[key])) {
        this.wordMap[key] = null; //duplicate
      } else {
        unique.add(this.wordMap[key]);
      }
    }
  }
  onDelete(index) {
    this.wordMap[index] = null;
  }
}
const dict = new SomeComponent();
dict.cleanWord();
console.log(dict.wordMap);

dict.onDelete(1);
console.log(dict.wordMap);
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: I ended up going with a solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use value as key, and keep the indexes as values

```
[
    "this is ": [0]
    "word": [1,3]
    " a form field value with another ":[2]
]
```

And then when you remove one index it will look like

```
[
    "this is ": [0]
    "word": [3]
    " a form field value with another ":[2]
]
```

---

You can use reduce to produce such format from your splitted string

```js
let str = ["this is ", "word", " a form field value with another ", "word"]

let mapperObj = str.reduce((op, inp, index) => {
  op[inp] = op[inp] || []
  op[inp].push(index)
  return op
}, {})

console.log(mapperObj)
```

Comment: @RobFyffe these are, you can never have duplicate property name in object

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything as the key, to the best of my knowledge, but you want them to be unique for each item.

I'd recommend base64'ing your item using `btoa(JSON.stringify(object))` or creating a unique key like mentioned above by appending index to value, `${index}${value}`

Comment: In React the keys must be unique. The same words would have the same key. Then removing the a value from the array would change the index so this means the key would not be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index as key if you can mark deleted values as `null`. This value can be rendered without additional filtering.